# Using external HDD as a programming environment

Tags: linux, hard-drive

I'd like to set up a programming environment separate from my Windows OS, and I don't want to partition my internal drive. I was thinking of installing a linux distro to an external USB hard drive and using that as a sandbox for doing programming work like trying out new languages/libraries without cluttering up my Windows system. My question is, will this be fast enough to use as a dedicated environment? If not, are there any other options I can pursue aside from partitioning my internal hard drive or using a virtual machine. My understanding is that virtual machines aren't all that fast anyway.

Comment: Most VMs are faster than you. Pick one that you can access from anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are literally thousands of folks all over the world doing exactly what you want to do. But I'm afraid *you* will have to be the final judge of whether a Linux VM on a USB hard drive is "fast enough". Nothing like giving it a go yourself to know for sure ;-)

I personally have several VMs (both Windows and Linux) set up on a portable 2TB USB 3.0 hard drive, which I use extensively. Sure, the VMs are slower than bare metal - you will notice the difference - but IMO they are very usable.

My advice (based *entirely* on my own personal experience, which is why there are no references here):

- Use a reasonably modern host PC (Intel 3rd-gen i5/i7 CPUs or later run VMs very nicely, even the laptop variants)
- If your host PC has 4GB RAM or less, install more RAM (8GB is all I need, you may want more depending on how much RAM you want to assign your VMs and how many VMs you want to run at the same time)
- Use a USB3 hard drive plugged into a USB3 port
- As for choice of guest OS, I would highly recommend something light like Linux Mint MATE. After trying many distributions, IMO Mint MATE virtualizes better than anything else. You can virtualize either 32-bit or 64-bit OS, depending on your needs. I find 32-bit VMs run a bit faster than 64-bit ones, but in the end you have to go with what you need to code against.
- When you configure your VM, I'd highly recommend a ONE CPU configuration. In almost every respect I have found that TWO or FOUR CPU configurations perform *worse* for most tasks, compared to a ONE CPU configuration. This is true for both VirtualBox and VMWare Workstation. I believe that this has a lot to do with the difficulties involved in virtualizing multiple CPUs (apparently there's a whole bunch of overhead in doing so).
- If you want solid, mature, well-performing accelerated 3D graphics inside your VM, I would suggest going with VMWare Workstation (Pro or Player Pro, the latter being free for non-commercial use). VirtualBox has experimental support for accelerated 3D graphics but, frankly, it's not even close to good enough. This is where VMWare's offerings really shine. Personally I don't need 3D acceleration in any of my VMs so I prefer, hands down, VirtualBox.

Have fun!

Comment: Wow, this is great. Thanks for such a detailed response. My PC (although it is a laptop) meets those requirements that you listed so I'll try the external solution. It sounds like it can't be too slow, since you're running an external OS and VM on top of that!

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine with VMs. But it all depends of your PC configuration. If you have a low-end pc without spare RAM for VM, go for external solution, just try to use at least USB 3.0 if creating partition and dual boot isnt a option.

Or find old PC or laptop and make it workstation.